# FileHandler.limit java 7 not working

Tags: java, file, logging, filehandler

I have problem with java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit property as file size exceeded the limit size 
here are used properties in my application

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ATMChannelAdapter%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 2000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

it works fine and then at some point application writes in only one file with no limit beyond the configuration file size riches 1 GB approximately and to back to normal configuration I have to restart my application.

operating system is windows server 2012
java 7

does anyone have similar issue? is this could be happened in high load?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your posted config the whole configuration?
I am missing a line like `handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler`

Comment: there are  more configuration properties handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler ,java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level= INFO 'java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter'

Comment: I also noticed that count and size working will in first roll, then when the 10th file reached limit no more rolling and continue writing to last file in order

Comment: The configuration looks OK, it should work as expected. Have you tried to instanciate and configure a FileHandler via code? `FileHandler(String pattern, int limit, int count)`. Can you try this one out? If the configuration via Code works, I guess some kind of problems with reading the config file itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am already using this constructor and I am facing this issue, I thought this related to JDK 7

Comment: java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=channel_adapter_logging.properties -jar app.jar

Answer (score 0):

Something is resetting your LogManager properties or you are running in to [java.util.logging.FileHandler integer overflow prevents file rotation](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-August/028286.html).  Try to install the following formatter which looks at the conditions that prevent rotation.

```
public class FileSimpleFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {

    private static final Field METER;
    private static final Field COUNT;

    static {
        try {
            METER = FileHandler.class.getDeclaredField("meter");
            METER.setAccessible(true);

            COUNT = FileHandler.class.getDeclaredField("count");
            COUNT.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    private volatile FileHandler h;

    @Override
    public String getHead(Handler h) {
        this.h = FileHandler.class.cast(h);
        return super.getHead(h);
    }

    private String check() {
        FileHandler target = h;
        if (target != null) {
            try {
                Object os = METER.get(target);
                if (os != null && os.getClass().getName().endsWith("MeteredStream")) {
                    Field written = os.getClass().getDeclaredField("written");
                    written.setAccessible(true);
                    Number c = Number.class.cast(COUNT.get(target));
                    Number w = Number.class.cast(written.get(os));
                    if (c.intValue() <= 0 || w.intValue() < 0) {
                        return String.format("target=%1$s count=%2$s written=%3$s%n",
                                target, c, w);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw (Error) new IllegalAccessError(ex.getMessage()).initCause(ex);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                throw (Error) new NoSuchFieldError(ex.getMessage()).initCause(ex);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return super.format(record).concat(check());
    }
}
```

Then search your log file to see if it found anything.

**Update:** Oracle is working this issue under [JDK-8059767
FileHandler should allow 'long' limits and handle overflow of MeteredStream.written.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059767)